# xamarin Android: Want to create group in navigation view menu item programmatically

Tags: android, xamarin.android

```
  <group  android:id="@+id/grpTest1"> </group><groupandroid:id="@+id/grpTest2"></group>
```

i want to create group and group ID dynamically which can perform above code task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the group with menuitem, but you can't create an empty group.

You could use `Add (Int32 groupId, Int32 itemId, Int32 order, ICharSequence title)` to do that. The `groupId` is the id you want to set to the group. It only takes Int, you can set a value in string.xml:

```
        <string name="grpTest1">grpTest1</string>
```

And add item by using:

```
        menu.Add(Resource.String.grpTest1, Menu.None, 0, "Item 1");
        menu.Add(Resource.String.grpTest1, Menu.None, 0, "Item 2");
        menu.Add(Resource.String.grpTest1, Menu.None, 0, "Item 3");
```

These three menuitems will be in the same group.